# Why is there an indent in span tag

Tags: css

I wanted to make two inline-block span tags just to try it out but when the width of second span is below 50px or so the first span is placed lower.
Everything works fine when width is bigger or if I delete word from the second span.

Html code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="eng">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Docume2nt</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <span id="span1">Hi</span>
    <span id="span2">Hi man</span>
</body>
</html>
```

Css code:

```
#span1{
        background: palevioletred;
}
#span2{
    background: lightskyblue;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 200px;
    width: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the `vertical-align` property for the first span. It's aligning it at the text's baseline by default I think. Change it like:

```css
#span1 {
  background: palevioletred;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

Working code: https://jsfiddle.net/vfk650o7/

Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align

Comment: Thanks, do you have an idea why it changes depending on the width of second span?

Comment: It's using the inner text's baseline, when you don't have enough room it wraps into 2 lines and the baseline is the last line I guess.